# How to break lines in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, line-breaks

I am [*completely new to PowerShell and*] concatenating a string in a loop, if a special condition occurs I should **insert a line break...how can I do this?**

Basically looking for the equivalent of `\n`.

```bsh
$str = ""
foreach($line in $file){
  if($line -Match $review){ #Special condition
    $str += ANSWER #looking for ANSWER
  }
  #code.....
}
```

So far I have tried

```
"\n" '\n' "\N" '\N' "\r" '\r' "\R" '\R' '`n' '`r' '-n' '-r'
```

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Try `` "`n" `` with double quotes. (**not** single quotes `` '`n' `` )

For a complete list of escaping characters see:

`Help about_Escape_character`

The code should be

```
$str += "`n"
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work.
it  gives me `The term '
' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, sc....`

Comment: The examples in `Help about_Escape_character` helped me to figure out the problem. Editing answer to show the solution

Comment: So to split a multiline string, use `$filestobackup = $files.split("\`n");`

Answer (score 20):

If you are using just code like this below, you must put just a **grave accent** at the end of line `` ` ``.

```
docker run -d --name rabbitmq `
           -p 5672:5672 `
           -p 15672:15672 `
           --restart=always `
           --hostname rabbitmq-master `
           -v c:\docker\rabbitmq\data:/var/lib/rabbitmq `
           rabbitmq:latest
```

Comment: Thank You, tilda works for newlines in Powershell code

Answer (score 10):

I think I found it. All you have to do is type in "`n" (WITH THE QUOTATION MARKS!)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone else comes across this, to clarify the answer `n is grave accent n, not single tick n

Comment: It's actually a "grave accent". A tilde is ~

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: No, ǹ is grave accent n and `n is backtick n. Not sure why you think otherwise. Please post a reference if I am missing something.

Comment: @ChrisBroski, the grave accent and the backtick are the same thing, as per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtick). I agree that describing it as "backtick n" is less ambiguous than "grave accent n" for the reason you mentioned.

Comment: @Bren0man the difference is the the placement of the mark in relation to the letter - the accent is above and the back tick precedes it.

Answer (score 3):

You can also just use:

```
Write-Host "";
```

Or, to put it in terms of your specific question:

```
$str = ""
foreach($line in $file){
  if($line -Match $review){ #Special condition
    $str += Write-Host ""
    $str += ANSWER #looking for ANSWER
  }
  #code.....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If escaping doesn't work, you can try this:

`$str += $("" | Out-String)`

It just adds nothing, but as an `Out-String`, which creates a new line.